# how to copy custom text in flutter to clipboard?

Tags: flutter, clipboard

need a way to copy a custom text that i give it a `font-style` and other styles if possible in my flutter app, currently while working on my app i can `copy` the text i want to clipboard and use it later but with out any style.

this is how now i copy the text which dont work for me the way i want.

```
ClipboardData data = ClipboardData(text:sample);
Clipboard.setData(data);`
```

this is how i can copy the default text but insted i want to copy a custom text like next.

```
Text(
   sample,
   style: TextStyle(
   fontSize: 20,
   fontFamily: IndieFlower,
     ),
  )`
```